# Powershell : Select -skip 2 |Remove-Item -Force not working correctly.

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I want to write a powershell script to keep the latest 2 files and delete other older files.
I also want to skip a certain folder called "DIFF". I am trying to write the script with many conditions to keep folders, cmd and ps1 file.

There is no errors in the console but the files are not removed correctly. I want to keep the latest 2, it is only keeping the latest 1 file.

```
 Get-ChildItem $directorypath -Recurse |where {$_.extension -ne ".ps1" -and $_.extension -ne ".cmd"}| Where-Object{!($_.PSIsContainer) } | Where {$_.FullName -notmatch 'DIFF'}| sort $_.LastWriteTime -desc|select -Skip 2 |Remove-Item -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

I should use Select-Object -Skip 2 instead.

```
  Get-ChildItem $directorypath -Recurse |where {$_.extension -ne ".ps1" -and $_.extension -ne ".cmd"}| Where-Object{!($_.PSIsContainer) } | Where {$_.FullName -notmatch 'DIFF'}| sort CreationTime -desc|Select-Object -Skip 2 |Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: Something weird going on then since Select is just an alias for Select-Object